# Is one allowed to use neighbor's overhanging tree branches for schach?

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, sukkah, trees, dina-dmalchusa-dina, schach

The Shulchan Aruch in [CM 155:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.155.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) rules that if the neighbor's overhanging tree branches present a nuisance, one is allowed to cut them until the property line.

1. Is one allowed to cut these branches if the nuisance is very minor (or even imaginary), such as being a possible extra dwelling spot for unwelcome insects or bothering the person because beautiful branches are going to waste instead of being used for a mitzvah?
2. Whom do the cut branches belong to?
3. How would the Secular Law affect the halacha on above?

Comment: 1. THis is subject to local laws 2. Once the branches are allowed to be cut, it is considered as if the owner made them Hefker. 3. see #1

Comment: I personally have a wireless chainsaw and periodically trim the branches of the trees that interfere with the passage on sidewalks of my neighborhood in Jerusalem.

Comment: 1. There needs to be some kind of damage like loss of sunlight, perhaps insects or such. Wasteful branches is highly unlikely to qualify as a damage. 2. They belong to the owner of the tree. 3. If both neighbors are jewish then they should be bound by Jewish law not secular law just like any other monetary dispute that goes to bais din see- https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/if-a-neighbors-tree-is-encroaching-onto-ones-property/#_ftn7

Comment: related - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37461/can-i-eat-the-fruits-overhanging-from-my-neighbors-tree

Comment: For 2&3 in UK Law you can cut the branches that are overhanging. However, they must be given back to the neighbour unless you have permission to do what you want with them. Also, in areas where it’s public you need to have permission from the council. So, I would say yes secular law do play a part. Furthermore, I always ask the neighbour every year for permission even though i know they will say yes. You should never assume!